# What's the microscopic and macroscopic effect of wavefunction dispersion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dispersion

In Quantum Mechanics (Merzbacher 2nd ed.), problem 2.1 asks us to derive the time evolution of a one-dimensional Gaussian wavefunction (formula given for $t=0$), assuming the velocity is in the $+x$ direction. It then asks us to apply the result to calculate the effects of wavefunction spreading to  microscopic and macroscopic experiments.

I did the calculation for a single particle of mass $m$ and, WLOG setting the mean wavenumber $\bar{k}=0$, came up with the result that the spreading of $\|\psi^2\|$ happened at a rate of about $\hbar/2m$, which is extremely small on macroscopic scales even for many elementary particles and molecules.

My questions are:

1. **Since the width of the wavefunction is inversely related to that of its Fourier transform (HUP), does this mean that over time the particle's momentum becomes better defined?**
2. **Would this calculated rate be the actual rate at which a beam of particles (all of mass $m$) disperses?**

Comment: "*Since the width of the wavefunction is inversely related to that of its Fourier transform (HUP), does this mean that over time the particle's momentum becomes better defined?*" note that the HUP states that $\Delta x$ times $\Delta p$ is **grater** or equal to $\hbar/2$. This means that $\Delta x$ can increase over time, while keeping $\Delta p$ constant, for example. Therefore, we cannot conclude that the momentum distribution gets narrower. You can try to calculate $\Delta p$ as a function of time, and try to check this claim yourself (which might or might not be true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to your first question, when you calculate the time-evolution of a wavepacket, you first transform your wavepacket representation from a positional basis to a momentum basis.
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_k c_{x,p}|p\rangle
$$
This moment basis is useful as they are eigenstates to your hamiltonian and satisfy
$$
H |p\rangle = E_p |p\rangle
$$
This in turn allows you apply the time-evolution operator to your initial wavepacket giving
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_p c_{x,p}e^{i H t/\hbar}|p\rangle = \sum_p c_{x,p}e^{i E_p t/\hbar}|p\rangle
$$
using this basis, you can easily calculate the expectation value of your momentum p.
$$
\langle\psi(t)|\hat{p}|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_{p,p'} c_{x,p}c^{\dagger}_{x,p'}e^{-i E_{p'} t/\hbar}e^{i E_p t/\hbar}\langle p'|\hat{p}|p\rangle
$$
So now notice that the last term is simply the momentum times a delta function!  This mean that p = p' and one of the sums disappear.  Also, $E_p = E_{p'}$ so the term that has time is also killed! Thus you are left with
$$
\langle\psi(t)|\hat{p}|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_{p} p c_{x,p}c^{\dagger}_{x,p}
$$
which does not change with time.  You can apply the same argument to a p^2 operator as well to find that you do not gain or lose information on the momentum across time.

Comment: [note that you can use `\langle` for $\langle$ and `\rangle` for $\rangle$, which look much better that <>; also, the symbol for a dagger is `\dagger`] In your first equation, what is $x$ and what is $k$?

Comment: Thanks!  I knew all of these things at one point... Sadly i don't get to draw to many langles or rangles anymore...